# make:command not defined in Laravel 5.1.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to use the `make:console` to create a scheduler, however it's returning:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]              
  Command "make:console" is not defined. 
  Did you mean one of these?       
     make:seeder                         
     make:migration
```

Fair enough if this was before version 5.0, but I'm currently using 5.1.7. What could cause this issue?

Here's a list of the current available commands:

```
  help                Displays help for a command
  list                Lists commands
  migrate             Run the database migrations
  serve               Serve the application on the PHP development server
 cache
  cache:clear         Flush the application cache
  cache:table         Create a migration for the cache database table
 db
  db:seed             Seed the database with records
 make
  make:migration      Create a new migration file
  make:seeder         Create a new seeder class
 migrate
  migrate:install     Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh     Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset       Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback    Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status      Show the status of each migration
 queue
  queue:failed        List all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:failed-table  Create a migration for the failed queue jobs database table
  queue:flush         Flush all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:forget        Delete a failed queue job
  queue:listen        Listen to a given queue
  queue:restart       Restart queue worker daemons after their current job
  queue:retry         Retry a failed queue job
  queue:subscribe     Subscribe a URL to an Iron.io push queue
  queue:table         Create a migration for the queue jobs database table
  queue:work          Process the next job on a queue
 schedule
  schedule:run        Run the scheduled commands
```

If I modify `composer.json` to version 5.2.* I receive an even slimmer selection of commands:

```
  help              Displays help for a command
  list              Lists commands
  migrate           Run the database migrations
 cache
  cache:clear       Flush the application cache
 db
  db:seed           Seed the database with records
 make
  make:migration    Create a new migration file
 migrate
  migrate:install   Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh   Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset     Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback  Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status    Show the status of each migration
 queue
  queue:failed      List all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:flush       Flush all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:forget      Delete a failed queue job
  queue:listen      Listen to a given queue
  queue:restart     Restart queue worker daemons after their current job
  queue:retry       Retry a failed queue job
  queue:work        Process the next job on a queue
 schedule
  schedule:run      Run the scheduled commands
```

Comment: Your `make` command options seem seriously inadequate. There are no options for `controller`, `model`, etc. Please check your laravel installation for errors.

Comment: Perhaps try running `composer update`. As @linuxartisan suggests you are lacking a number of commands that **should** be there.

Comment: Yeah I have noticed that as well. Running `composer update` updated a number of the illuminate components however I'm still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @Jake Try creating a brand-new Laravel app and copy your configuration and files over.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 The application is a little old and cumbersome to replicate since it was a previous person's work, so while I did try this, it ended up being easier to find a work-around instead. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find a work-around. Even though my Laravel CLI was missing the previously mentioned commands, I still had the scheduling and command file structure to manipulate.

Manually create `example_scheduled_command.php` in the `Commands` directory and register it in `Kernal.php`. Then you can utilise that for Laravel Scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but I could resolve it using

```
php artisan make:console AssignUsers --command=users:assign
```

And then register the command in app/Console/Kernel.php

see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands

Answer (score 0):

Try

## php artisan make:command nameCommand

to run it : 
try php artisan nameCommand

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I had the same problem with "schedule:work", I solved it by manually adding it to app/console/kernel.php

```
protected $commands = [
    Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleWorkCommand::class
]
```

There are a lot of commands available in Illuminate folder, but there are not displayed in "artisan list"